# Modifying parent array from child component - React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm building a React app, I need to store the handlers for all windows I open from the app (ye it's a bit weird but it's what I have to do). Before using React I was storing the windows on a global array atached to the parent window (I know JS global variables are a really bad practice but it was specified in the project to do so).

**I would like not to use Redux and try to solve this with only React.**

In the new React app I have this array declared on the state of the App component, and a method to manipulate the stae which I'm passing as a prop to the child component:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { name: 'Desktop', openedWindows: [] };        

    this.handleStateChange = this.handleStateChange.bind(this)
  }  

   handleStateChange(param) {
     this.setState({
     openedWindows: [
       ...this.state.openedWindows,
       param
     ]
})
```

}

```
  render() {   
    const themes = ['#2c2f33', 'teal']
    const backgroundColor = themes[0]          

    return (
      this.state.name === 'Desktop' ?
      <div className='App'>
        <Header backgroundColor = {backgroundColor} />
        <Landing backgroundColor = {backgroundColor} 
          handleStateChange = {this.handleStateChange} />
        <Footer backgroundColor = {backgroundColor}/>
      </div>
      :
      <div className='App'>
        <Header backgroundColor = {backgroundColor} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is the child component trying to change the state:

```
class Landing extends Component {
    handleOpenWindow = () => {     
        let newWindow = window.open('', '_blank')
        this.props.handleStateChange= this.props.handleStateChange.bind(this)
    }

    render () {
        const { backgroundColor } = this.props
        return (            
            <div className='landing'>
                <button className='btn' 
                    onClick={this.handleOpenWindow}
                    style={{backgroundColor}}
                >Abrir Editor
                </button>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Landing
```

I get a TypeError: Bind must be called on a function

I've tried different approaches on the call of the function, but I can't get this to work. Don't know what I'm doing wrong or if this is possible without using Redux.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: is `this.handleStateChange = this.handleStateChange.bind.bind(this)` copy paste error?

Comment: It's a typo, I'm modyfing and editing the post

Comment: you dont need `this.props.handleStateChange= this.props.handleStateChange.bind(this)`. just invoke `this.props.handleStateChange(newWindow)`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues:

There is a typo in the constructor: `this.handleStateChange.bind.bind(this)`
that is one `.bind` too much.

In `handleStateChange(param)` the state update is wrong:
It should be

```
this.setState({
  openedWindows: [
    ...this.state.openedWindows,
    param
  ]
})
```

Comment: I changed it but now i get TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: In the `Landing` component you don't have to bind this. Just assign onClick={this.props.handleStateChange}

Answer (score 0):

You have to make changes in the child component's `handleOpenWindow()` like,

```
    handleOpenWindow = () => {     
        let newWindow = window.open('', '_blank')
        this.props.handleStateChange(newWindow);
    }
```

You have to pass the opened window object back to your parent as a param and you dont need to bind it here.
  Rest looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Parent Component

//create an array in state.

```
`constructor(props){
     this.state={
         name:[]
     } 
 }`
```

now create a function which accepts an array as an argument and setState

```
handleChange=(value)=>{
    this.setState({name:value});
}
```

Now pass the function as a prop to the child component and then you can pass the value(argument) from the child which would eventually do a setState in the parent component

Child component

```
`setData=()=>{
    let name=[1,2,3,4];
    this.props.handleChange(name); 
 }`
```

make sure you pass the function to the child component.
This will help you set the state in a parent from a child component.